# Trouble implementing const_iterator in c++

Tags: c++, iterator, c++98

I'm struggling trying to implement a const_iterator to my container class, I did a short reproductible example with a basic array to show the problem (I know that `std::iterator` is deprecated but this is for a project in C++98 standard):

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>

template <
    typename T
> struct remove_const { typedef T type; };
template <
    typename T
> struct remove_const < const T > { typedef T type; };

template <
    typename T
> struct add_const { typedef const T type; };

template <
    class T,
    std::size_t size
> class Array {
    public:
        template <
            class U
        > class base_iterator : public std::iterator <
            std::random_access_iterator_tag,
            U
        > {
            public:
                typedef std::iterator <
                    std::random_access_iterator_tag,
                    U
                >   iterator_type;

                base_iterator() : ptr(NULL) { }
                base_iterator(U *p) : ptr(p) { }
                base_iterator(const base_iterator &other) : ptr(other.ptr) { }
                base_iterator(const base_iterator< remove_const< U > > &other) : ptr(other.ptr) { }
                base_iterator(const base_iterator< add_const< U > > &other) : ptr(other.ptr) { }

                base_iterator   &operator =(const base_iterator &other) {
                    ptr = other.ptr;
                    return *this;
                }
                base_iterator   &operator =(const base_iterator< remove_const< U > > &other) {
                    ptr = other.ptr;
                    return *this;
                }
                base_iterator   &operator =(const base_iterator< add_const< U > > &other) {
                    ptr = other.ptr;
                    return *this;
                }
                U               &operator *(void) { return *ptr; }
                U               &operator *(void) const { return *ptr; }
                U               *operator ->(void) { return ptr; }
                U               *operator ->(void) const { return *ptr; }
                base_iterator   &operator ++(void) {
                    ++ptr;
                    return *this;
                }
                base_iterator   operator ++(int) {
                    return base_iterator(ptr++);
                }
                base_iterator   &operator --(void) {
                    --ptr;
                    return *this;
                }
                base_iterator   operator --(int) {
                    return base_iterator(ptr++);
                }
                base_iterator   operator +(const typename iterator_type::difference_type &amount) const {
                    return base_iterator(ptr + amount);
                }
                base_iterator   operator -(const typename iterator_type::difference_type &amount) const {
                    return base_iterator(ptr - amount);
                }
                base_iterator   &operator +=(const typename iterator_type::difference_type &amount) {
                    ptr += amount;
                    return *this;
                }
                base_iterator   &operator -=(const typename iterator_type::difference_type &amount) {
                    ptr -= amount;
                    return *this;
                }
                bool            operator ==(const base_iterator &other) const {
                    return ptr == other.ptr;
                }
                bool            operator !=(const base_iterator &other) const {
                    return ptr != other.ptr;
                }
                bool            operator <(const base_iterator &other) const {
                    return ptr < other.ptr;
                }
                bool            operator <=(const base_iterator &other) const {
                    return ptr <= other.ptr;
                }
                bool            operator >(const base_iterator &other) const {
                    return ptr > other.ptr;
                }
                bool            operator >=(const base_iterator &other) const {
                    return ptr >= other.ptr;
                }
            private:
                U   *ptr;
        };
        typedef base_iterator< T >                      iterator;
        typedef base_iterator< const T >                const_iterator;
        typedef std::reverse_iterator< iterator >       reverse_iterator;
        typedef std::reverse_iterator< const_iterator > const_reverse_iterator;

        iterator                begin(void) { return iterator(data); }
        const_iterator          begin(void) const { return const_iterator(data); }
        iterator                end(void) { return iterator(data + size); }
        const_iterator          end(void) const { return const_iterator(data + size); }
        reverse_iterator        rbegin(void) { return reverse_iterator(data + size - 1); }
        const_reverse_iterator  rbegin(void) const { return const_reverse_iterator(data + size - 1); }
        reverse_iterator        rend(void) { return reverse_iterator(data - 1); }
        const_reverse_iterator  rend(void) const { return const_reverse_iterator(data - 1); }

    private:
        T   data[size];
};

int main(void) {
    Array< int, 20 >    a;

    for (Array< int, 20 >::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
        *it = 42;
    for (Array< int, 20 >::const_iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

the compiler outputs

```
problem.cpp:106:40: error: no viable conversion from 'base_iterator<int>' to 'base_iterator<const int>'
        for (Array< int, 20 >::const_iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
                                              ^    ~~~~~~~~~
problem.cpp:24:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Array<int, 20>::iterator' (aka 'base_iterator<int>') to 'const int *' for 1st argument
                                base_iterator(U *p) : ptr(p) { }
                                ^
problem.cpp:25:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Array<int, 20>::iterator' (aka 'base_iterator<int>') to 'const Array<int, 20>::base_iterator<const int> &' for 1st argument
                                base_iterator(const base_iterator &other) : ptr(other.ptr) { }
                                ^
1 error generated.
```

So it seems that the problem is that `base_iterator< T >` is not convertible to `base_iterator< const T >`, but firstly I'm wondering why do we need a conversion ? As there are const overloads for `begin` and `end`, and `operator */->`, shouldn't it call the const versions?
And secondly if we need a conversion I can't figure out how to do this

EDIT 1: I implemented `remove_const` and `add_const` to do the conversion but it still doesn't compile

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but future bug you may encounter: `rbegin` should simply be `reverse_iterator(end())` (or `reverse_iterator(iterator(data + size))`), as `std::reverse_iterator` subtracts one for you when you dereference. Same for `rend` and `reverses_iterator(begin())`.

Comment: `add_const<U>` should be `typename add_const<U>::type`, same for `remove_const<U>`. (However, the current code will duplicate the copy constructor and assignment operator.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler is telling you that it can't convert your `iterator` to your `const_iterator`.

```
a.begin();
```

Since `a` is a mutable object, the `begin()` overload that returns an `iterator` gets called, but an attempt is made to store the result into a `const_iterator`, and the way you designed your iterator classes does not allow for that conversion to take place.

This is the same reason why you can't take, for example, a `std::vector<int>` and assign it, just like that, to `std::vector<const int>`. It's the same fundamental reason. `std::vector<int>` and `std::vector<const int>` are two completely different classes that are not related to each other in any form, or fashion. Your two iterator classes are in the same boat.

What you will need to do is redesign your iterator classes so that this kind of a conversion becomes trivial.

The classical way to handle this is to have `iterator` inherit from `const iterator`, something like:

```
class const_iterator {
protected:

    T *p;  // The underlying pointer, or whatever is being used to reference the iterator value and/or its container.

public:

    // Implement only the `const` methods here
};

class iterator : public const_iterator {

public:

    // Implement only the non-const methods here
};
```

Now, the magical conversion happens automatically, where needed. Both `iterator` and `const_iterator` have full complete access to the underlying container, and its values. `const_iterator` needs to only be careful enough to preserve `const`-correctness, i.e. its `operator*` overload return a `const T &`, while `iterator::operator*()` returns a `T &`, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that, it seems cleaner, I don't know why I only found my structure when searching for implementations

Comment: This design pattern should be explained in every C++ textbook that specializes in C++ library algorithms and containers. This is why you can't really learn C++ from random Google searches or Youtube videos, but only from a reputable textbook.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not the `const` qualified version of the member function is called, depends only on whether the type of the expression on which the member function is called is `const` qualified.

In `a.begin()` in your example `a` is declared as `Array< int, 20 >` which is not `const`. So the non-`const`-qualified version of `begin()` will be called.

If you want to have your container class compliant with the *Container* requirement in the C++ standard library, then you must make your `iterator` convertible to `const_iterator`. This is one of the stated requirements and would make your test code work as expected.

For a full list of *Container* requirements see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I implemented `add_const` and `remove_const` to make the conversion but it doesn't work, how should we do this conversion?

Comment: @Fayeure Are you referring to `std::add_const` and `std::remove_const`? I don't know how they would help here. You have multiple possibilities to make the conversion work: Make `iterator` and `const_iterator` two classes. Either let both inherit from `base_iterator` and have `const_iterator` take a converting constructor or give `iterator` a user-defined conversion operator. See also the other answer for an alternative approach.

Comment: @Fayeure Also as an aside, for your kind of container that just uses a simple array as linear storage, a pointer is sufficient as iterator. There is no need for anything but `typedef T* iterator; typedef const T* const_iterator;` and so on.

Comment: I know, it was just a simple reproductive example, my real container is a red black tree, the project is to implement `std::map` and `std::vector`, so I needed to implement an iterator class for `map`, but of course I just use a regular pointer for my `vector`